# Regex that Replaces [number] from String

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I want to remove [number] from string;

**input** examples are:

1 - home address  [my first home address #12] **[1350]** 
2 - some text here  (some text here) some
3 - hello dolor sit amet [kost street #74] **[1008]**

**Output** examples are:

1 - home address  [my first home address #12] 
2 - some text here  (some text here) some
3 - hello dolor sit amet [kost street #74]

**What I've tried**

```
var pattern = @"^[\d+]$";
var result = Regex.Replace(value, pattern, "");
```

I wanna remove bold text with its quadratic symbols "**[**" & "**]**" and if it doesn't contain it at all, then leave as it is(see second example).

Comment: please, indicate the reason of -1

Comment: please show us what you tried so far

Comment: Also show us the expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: With ^(`beginning of string`) and $(`end of string`) you won't be able to match the pattern if it's in between the string

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you tried `"^[\d+]$` was almost correct! The problem with that pattern is that you are using the anchors `^...$` which basically denote that the pattern will only match the digits encapsulated in braces if they are the ONLY string of characters in the input. [See the MSDN documentation on Anchors for a more technical summary.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#atomic_zerowidth_assertions)

The pattern `\[\d+\]` will match any digits encapsulated in square braces.

Using `Regex.Replace` :-

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\[\d+\]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: I think this conforms to your expected input and output but I am also under the impression that you want to strip the braces and leave the number? Question is still not clear.

Comment: @FabianBigler, your pattern won't work.  It should be `@"\[\d+\]"` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
input = "home address [my first home address #12] [1350]"
string pattern = @"\[\d+\]";
string replacement = " ";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Update: (After the question was updated with some code...)

```
var pattern = @"^[\d+]$";
```

This pattern will only work against numbers.  The following pattern should work for you:

```
var pattern = @"\[\d+\]";
```

Comment: I have a feeling that he provides the number.

Answer (score 0):

For your examples, you don't need a regex.

```
string address = "home address [my first home address #12] [1350]";

if(address.Count(x => x == '[') >= 2))
   address = address.Substring(0, address.LastIndexOf('['));
```

Comment: On the surface you're right this does resolve the example. However the first line does have a whitespace character at the end of the string which was carried forward to the desired output see: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17380604/edit. Your solution here will remove that whitespace.

Comment: I thought that was a mistake. In that case, you can remove the `Trim()` method at the end as that was only added to remove the extra space. (I've updated the answer)